# C# does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and the best extension method overload requires a receiver of type 'Task'

Tags: c#, async-await

I am trying to make a GTA 5 Cheat I have the injector done and am working on the UI. I have tried to delete await taskAwaiter; from my code and it would not launch at that point
My code:

```
TaskAwaiter<string> taskAwaiter = (await MainWindow.client.PostAsync("https://pastebin.com/Mypaste", new FormUrlEncodedContent(nameValueCollection))).Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter();
if (!taskAwaiter.IsCompleted)
{
    await taskAwaiter;
    TaskAwaiter<string> taskAwaiter2;
    taskAwaiter = taskAwaiter2;
    taskAwaiter2 = default(TaskAwaiter<string>);
}
if (taskAwaiter.GetResult() != "success")
{
    this.UpdateStatus("Auth failed");
    this.TimeoutReset();
    this.cant_click = false;
}
else
{
    this.UpdateStatus("Logged in");
    File.WriteAllText(this.auth_file, this.user.ToString());
    this.Download();
}
```

Comment: You'll find that your code is much easier to debug if you resist the temptation to string function call after function call after function call.  Remember that if you create a temporary variable in your code (for an intermediate result), consume it in the next line of code and never use it again, then the JITter will very likely optimize that temporary away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `await` operator isn't meant to be used with an awaiter - it calls `GetAwaiter` itself (if necessary).

It's not really clear what you're trying to achieve here, and this *looks* like half-decompiled code, but I suspect you just want something like:

```cs
using (var response = await MainWindow.client.PostAsync("https://pastebin.com/Mypaste", new FormUrlEncodedContent(nameValueCollection)))
{
    var text = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    if (text == "Success")
    {
        UpdateStatus("Logged in");
        File.WriteAllText(auth_file, user.ToString());
        Download();
    }
    else
    {
        UpdateStatus("Auth failed");
        TimeoutReset();
        cant_click = false;
    }
}
```

In each case with this code, the `await` operator is used on a *task*, not on an *awaiter*.